# Soundcloud event loads same position after being fired once

Tags: jquery, events, variables, nested, soundcloud

I´m currently making a website that allows you to listen to music from various sources.
One creates a playlist and adds x amount of songs from youtube and soundcloud to it.

So far when one song has ended I used header(Location:) to send the user to the next position(positon and playlistid were a parameter in the url).

Now I want all this to happen without any redirecting.
So I put the player where the video loads in a nested div and load it on window load.
I also give the variable $position the value 1.
Now when one video ends(in this example I only use videos from soundcloud, youtube will be its own problem) I call the soundcloud event in the main page and I set the variable $position +1 in the end.

```
soundcloud.addEventListener('onMediaEnd', function(player, data) {
    <?php
    foreach ($db->query("select * from mytable where playlistid=$playlist and pos=$position") as $nextrows) {
    $link1=$nextrows['link'];

    ?>
        $("#videonested").load("mysite?link=<?php echo $link1;?>")
    <?php
    $position=$position+1;
    }
```

Now when I load the site the first video loads perfectly, when it ends the second video loads and everything works. but when the second video is finished it loads the second video again instead of the third. The variable $position is 2 as well.

What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to work with events like this? Or is there a better way than putting the player in a nested div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.
I now use javascript to count the position and load the div with only the playlistid and the position as parameters. Then in the nested I use the GET method and make my foreach there.
Now for youtube....